# How can I use Python OpenCV to get the dimensions of each contoured object in the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, shapes, contour

I'm working on a project that involves automatically clicking on objects in a video game as they appear on the screen. Naturally, each object has a distinct blue outline - so I've isolated all colors from the image except for that blue color.

The image below shows an example of a pre-processed screenshot of the game. Using OpenCV in Python, how can I:

- Get the position of the center-most pixel of each object?
- Get the position of the top-most pixel of each object?

[image: Image of three similar blobs]

E.g.,

[image: Image of three similar blobs with their centers and tops roughly pointed out]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a relatively less-known `cv2` method [`cv2.moments()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d49/tutorial_moments.html):

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contours:
    moments = cv2.moments(cnt)
    center_x = int(moments["m10"] / moments["m00"])
    center_y = int(moments["m01"] / moments["m00"])
    top_x, top_y = cnt[cnt[..., 1].argmin()][0]
    cv2.circle(img, (center_x, center_y), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(img, (top_x, top_y), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

The variable names explain the code pretty well already, after all, Python is similar to plain English!